# Can't resolve firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

[image: Hi, I'm trying to do a react clone with firebase backend, but for some reason it can't compile.I get a 'can't resolve firebase' message instead. None of the solutions I've found and employed have worked thus far.]

Hi, I'm trying to do a react clone with firebase backend, but for some reason it can't compile.I get a 'can't resolve firebase' message instead. None of the solutions I've found and employed have worked thus far.

Comment: Can you share the content of the `package.json` file?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the Firebase SDK 8 code but probably has installed the Firebase SDK 9 version. Your code should look like this with the new SDK:

```js
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth} from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "x",
  authDomain: "x",
  projectId: "x",
  storageBucket: "x",
  messagingSenderId: "x",
  appId: "x",
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth();
export { db, auth };
```

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) you can find more about the migration to the SDK 9 version.

Here is an example how to use the new SDK 9 with `collections`:

```js
import { collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collection(db, "cities"), () => {
  // Respond to data
  // ...
});

// Later ...

// Stop listening to changes
unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks Tarik,That seems to have resolved that problem. But now when I use the Useeffect hook, it says db.collection is not a function. Any ideas whats causing that? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Pls try to use from the firebase documentation the instructions for the SDK version 9.